# Asp.Net MVC3 with facebook chat api

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

How I can send facebook chat message to my facebook friends using an application asp.net mvc3?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Have you looked into the Facebook API at all?  Start with determining how you integrate or send a chat message in the first place.  Does Facebook provide documentation on this?  Where are you stuck in implementing what's documented?

Comment: @David Yes Facebook provide documentation for PHP https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/  thanks,

Comment: @ramo: Looks like it's mainly an XMPP service, which is a common standard.  A quick Google search turned up an XMPP library for .NET: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/